# why sharepoint doesn't look into sub-folders for control templates by default

Tags: 2007, custom-list, user-controls

I wonder why sharepoint doesn't look into sub-folders of control templates in 12 hive, even tho by default its suppose to.

I googled and seen people loading it from custom location in there code but what if you got a custom field control template, you got no code to load it, if its a sub-folder

any idea how things should be happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up copying files to control templates folder instead of into sub folder as it wasn't working and no way you can load it in a custom field template as far as I know.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)